# Plotting $(x^2 + y^2 - 1)^3 - x^2 y^3 = 0$

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions

I have no idea how this equation:
\begin{equation}
    (x^2 + y^2 - 1)^3 - x^2 y^3 = 0
\end{equation}

Produces this picture:

[image]

Can someone provide a general explanation of plotting this function?

Comment: The answer depends on what kind of software you wish to use. The picture you provide looks as if it has been generated by Mathematica. The command would be ContourPlot[f[x,y],{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2}].

Comment: @Eckhard: I'm asking of some explanation like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/54568/21440).

Comment: Let x=0, and you immediately get y=+/- 1.  Then let y=0, and you immediately get x=+/-1.  The rest is just interpolation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution set is obviously symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis. Therefore we may assume $x\geq 0$. In the domain $\{(x,y)\in {\mathbb R}^2\ |\ x\geq0\}$ the equation is equivalent with
$$x^2+ y^2 -1=x^{2/3} y\ ,$$
which can easily be solved for $y$:
$$y={1\over2}\bigl(x^{2/3}\pm\sqrt{x^{4/3}+4(1-x^2)}\bigr)\ .$$
Now plot this, taking both branches of the square root into account. You might have to numerically solve the equation $x^{4/3}+4(1-x^2)=0$ in order to get the exact $x$-interval.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to be understood in polar coordinates.

```
(x^2 + y^2 - 1)^3 - x^2*y^3 == 0 /. {x -> r*Cos[\[Theta]], 
   y -> r*Sin[\[Theta]]} // FullSimplify

% // ApplySides[#/r^5 &, #] &
```

$$
\left(r^2-1\right)^3=r^5 \sin ^3(\theta ) \cos ^2(\theta ) \\
\frac{\left(r^2-1\right)^3}{r^5}=\sin ^3(\theta ) \cos ^2(\theta )
$$

---

```
Plot[Sin[\[Theta]]^3*Cos[\[Theta]]^2, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[(r^2 - 1)^3/r^5, {r, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Starting from @Christian Blatter's solution
$$x^{\frac 43}+4(1-x^2)=0$$

$$x=t^{\frac 32} \qquad \implies \qquad 4 t^3-t^2-4=0$$

$$t=\frac{1}{12} \left(1+2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}(865)\right)\right)$$ When $a$ is large
$$ \cosh^{-1}(a)=(\log (a)+\log (2))-\frac{1}{4 a^2}-\frac{3}{32
   a^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^6}\right)$$ So

$$t\sim \frac{1}{12} \left(1+\sqrt[3]{2a}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2a}}\right)\qquad \text{where} \qquad a=865$$ which is in a absolute error of $1.106\times 10^{-7}$.