# How are the parametric equations describing the cupid curve derived?

Tags: trigonometry, parametric, graphing-functions

No doubt as some people have already seen, today morning wolfram posted the [best valentine ever](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cupid%20curve). The graph depicting cupid with its arrow and floating hearts around it involves something like 6 pages of parametric equations. My question to this community is, does any one have any idea how these equations were discovered? Is there a methodology here when people post equations with graphs looking like bunnies or hearts or is it just playing around with trigonometric functions with a little bit of intelligent guessing until something interesting pops out? Are there an papers/books/references on these type of derivations? No doubt these have been done for a while. I hope somebody at wolfram will publish something soon.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/288690/856 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17704/484

Comment: Second link is really good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics

Wolfram's Cupidon was made by trigonometrical "parts". Anyway, the basic idea is the same as with polynomial splines.
Take any advanced vector graphics editor (or modify or make such) - and you will get automatic derivation of such equations.

And heavy use of Heaviside Step Function in it (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeavisideStepFunction.html), if I'm correct, is only for masking/merging such fragmentation.