# Get a function (equation) from data points?

Tags: geometry, functions, graphing-functions

Is there a way to get a function (equation) from data points?

For example, we have this famous Google's 'Batman' function:
[image: Batman Graph]

> 2*sqrt(-abs(abs(x)-1)*abs(3-abs(x))/((abs(x)-1)*(3-abs(x))))(1+abs(abs(x)-3)/(abs(x)-3))sqrt(1-(x/7)^2)+(5+0.97(abs(x-.5)+abs(x+.5))-3(abs(x-.75)+abs(x+.75)))(1+abs(1-abs(x))/(1-abs(x))),-3sqrt(1-(x/7)^2)sqrt(abs(abs(x)-4)/(abs(x)-4)),abs(x/2)-0.0913722(x^2)-3+sqrt(1-(abs(abs(x)-2)-1)^2),(2.71052+(1.5-.5abs(x))-1.35526sqrt(4-(abs(x)-1)^2))sqrt(abs(abs(x)-1)/(abs(x)-1))+0.9

**^ How can I find this exact equation by only knowing the coordinates?**

Comment: You can't. Given a finite number of points, there are always an infinite number of functions containing all these points.

Comment: You might be interested in [Michael Trott's blog post](http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2013/05/17/making-formulas-for-everything-from-pi-to-the-pink-panther-to-sir-isaac-newton/) indicating how he automated the procedure to find *a* curve to mimic just about anything you want.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/288690/35416) is closely related, except it doesn't restrict to finding the curve *from points.*