# How are the wolfram alpha pikachu curve and others generated?

Tags: graphing-functions

If you type in "pikachu curve" or other famous fictional characters on wolfram alpha it generates a function to trace out the curve that resembles the character. See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pikachu+curve .

Does anyone know how these curves are generated? It seems that this has been done for several characters so I doubt that they worked out the details by hand.

Related: [Is this Batman equation for real?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54506/is-this-batman-equation-for-real)

[image]

Comment: I understand how to see that the curve is indeed what it says it is, I'm curious how such a curve could be generated given a trace of an image. More specifically how do they do it on wolfram alpha. I really doubt that they recognize what each part of the function does and piece it together themselves. Some of these curves are much more extensive that the Batman curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visit [Wolfram's blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/05/17/making-formulas-for-everything-from-pi-to-the-pink-panther-to-sir-isaac-newton/). It has many nice applications of *Mathematica*.