# How is equation art created

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, graphing-functions, plane-curves

A friend of mine sent me a [Wofram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=crystal%20maiden%20curve) link to a parametric curve that creates a detailed drawing of a game character.

[image]

The parametric equation that draws it is about ~9 screens tall on my computer; and appears to consist of thousands of sine's added together; unlike simpler examples like the [Batman Curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54506/is-this-batman-equation-for-real), this would have taken an enormous amount of effort to construct by hand; leaving me wondering how exactly is something like this created?

Answer (score 1):

My guess for this case:

The drawing was recorded as a sequence of $(x,y)$ couples, using a graphical editor. The coordinates were considered as functions of an independent parameter $t$, defining $x(t)$ and $y(t)$. (The simplest rule is to assign $t=\frac in$ to the $i^{th}$ point).

Then the [Fourier series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) mechanism allows to express these functions as sums of sinusoids of higher and higher frequencies, with computed phases and amplitudes, allowing to interpolate the curve for any $t$.

In addition, the Heaviside function was used to introduce discontinuities. How the two techniques were combined should be deeper scrutinized.