# Fourier Series of the batman equation

Tags: fourier-series, graphing-functions

I want to represent the batman equation as a Fourier Series.
(I got the equation here : [Is this Batman equation for real?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54506/is-this-batman-equation-for-real))
But a part of it is an ellipse and when I tried to calculate a<sub>n</sub> the integral was undefined.

Or is there any way where I can convert it as a single function, and not piece-wise.

Comment: From the analysis presented in the discussion of the Batman Equation it will take several piece wise sections of Fourier series to obtain the result.

Comment: So how do you think I should proceed with the ellipse?