# Is this graph plot for real?

Tags: graphing-functions, functional-equations

I came across this equation while surfing through the internet.Is this for real?If it is how is it done?

[image]

Comment: There's always Batman http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54506/is-this-batman-equation-for-real/152788#152788 :-).

Comment: You can graph function y = f(x) on rectangular coordinates.  Or you can graph the function $r = f(\theta)$ in polar coordinates where $\theta$ is an  angle and $r$ is a distance from (0,0).  This is a graph of such a function.

Comment: To elaborate on @fleablood's comment: You can create shapes with a polar plot that you cannot do with the usual $x$-$y$ plot of a function. (And the other way around.)

Comment: There's no rule that you can only graph functions.  if you graph $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ (or $r = 1$) get a circle and you can graph more than one thing.  Anything drawable can be graphed although the trick is coming up with a simple formula for the graph.  This heart one is one of the *least* surprising.  THe nice thing about this heart is that it *is* a single function.  Polar quardinates is nice for curves.  $r = \theta$ is a spiral that would be hard (but possible) to express in rectangular coordinates

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's real. You can try plotting it for yourself in Wolfram Alpha or some similar package. If your plotting package doesn't support polar coordinates, then you can convert to parametric equations in a rectangular coordinate system:
$$
x(\theta) = r(\theta)\cos(\theta) \quad ; \quad 
y(\theta) = r(\theta)\sin(\theta)
$$

There is even a well-known curve known as a [cardioid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid), which is fairly similar to your heart-shaped one. If you have been the victim of a classical education, you will know that "cardio" means "related to the heart".

Comment: Yeah...I have been a victim...

Comment: By the way why do you use the word *victim*?

Comment: Just for fun. Some people would say that a classical education (including Latin and Greek and so on) is a pointless and painful ordeal.

Comment: Ha ha....Greeks and Latin are funny!!!!

Comment: Can you please plot it on Wolfram and send me a link?

Comment: Here's [a simple cardiod](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ParametricPlot%5B%7B+2*Sin%5Bt%5D-Sin%5B2*t%5D,+2*Cos%5Bt%5D-Cos%5B2*t%5D%7D,+%7Bt,0,2*PI%7D%5D). You can type in your equation.