# Plotting anything on the cartesian plane?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, relations, polar-coordinates

I was playing around with the graphing application "Desmos", and came across a thought. Does there exist a way to plot any line or curve on the plane using one equation? This equation could be in the form of a polar equation, relation or function. For example, lets say I wanted to plot a smiley face or perhaps my name. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/05/17/making-formulas-for-everything-from-pi-to-the-pink-panther-to-sir-isaac-newton/).

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Anyone who was impressed by [this curve](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54506/is-this-batman-equation-for-real) should be amazed by those examples.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre very interesting. So there does exist a method however it is performed using programming. Do you know if something like that can come in a recurrence relation, where you maybe get an expression?

Comment: I really do not know. I guess it can be done, but I do not know how.