# How would I go about creating shapes on a graph?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, graphing-functions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObDLk.jpg)

I've been building shapes using piece wise functions however, for more complexed shapes and curves, I've been told to use parametric equations or multivariable equations. I want to know how to create certain unique curves as well as easy methods for creating polygons on a graph. I want to understand easier methods for creating say, shapes like the batman symbol without having to use tedious piece wise functions and instead find a way to create a single equation like this image here.

Comment: Any shape with corners is (likely) to need a piecewise definition. For smooth shapes, look up _splines_.

Comment: See [this posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54506/is-this-batman-equation-for-real) and replies.

Answer (score 0):

wow! I would love to know how interesting shapes can be created on graph, but I used to know that plotting $(x^2+y^2-1)^3 = x^2y^3$ gives us a love shape. for something that looks much as atom but when zoomed out looks like whatsapp default chat wallpaper plot $sin(x^2+y^2) = cos(xy)$.
but I feel that plotting specific interesting shapes like the Batman symbols would give rough polynomial or complex parametric stuff

Comment: I've built tanks and other symbols on graphs before using piece wise functions, its not too hard for those shapes, I've used existing shape equations to do it rather than a totally unique parametric or multivariable equation