# Does every shape on a graph fit an equation?

Tags: graphing-functions

For example, if someone draws a circle onto a graph, this will fit an equation of $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$.

However, if someone were to draw another shape, made up of seemingly random points (such as a portrait), would there be an equation that would form the same image if drawn onto a graph?

Comment: Depends on what you consider an equation. And of course this question *needs* a reference to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54506/is-this-batman-equation-for-real

Comment: The quick answer is yes, but not for any very interesting reason: if $X$ is any subset whatsoever of the plane, you can define a function $\chi_X$ (called the characteristic function of $X$) such that $\chi_X(x) = 1$ if $x \in X$ and $\chi_X(x) = 0$ otherwise. So $\chi_X(x) = 1$ is an equation whose solution set is $X$. If you place some more requirements on the equation (e.g., if you require it to involve only continuous functions or polynomials), then the question becomes more interesting.

Comment: Look a Tuppers formula for some interesting results.

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many more graphs in the plane than there are formulas we can write down. In fact, since equations must be written in finitely many characters from a finite alphabet, the number of possible equations - or definite descriptions of any kind - we can write is a countable infinity. However, there are uncountably many functions with different graphs on the plane.

Even the most jagged of curves  can be given a corresponding [Piecewise  function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise),for certain lengths of well known functions . One can also transform known functions to fit the given curve. You could also take some points and try to brute force a function which is true for all the points sampled